Changing 'upload-keystore.jks' for Flutter Android Build
After I created the new key, I am getting


What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)


I can only find the process for creating the first time. I don't know how to replace the exisiting key. Where can I find the way to replace the old one to the new one?
